# styling the outline border with outer overflow set to hidden

Tags: html, css

The **CSS** style:

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer:focus {
  outline: 10px solid #00FF00;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #F0F;
  left: 50%;
}

.inner:focus {
  outline: 10px solid #FFFF00;
}
```

The **HTML** code:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="outer">
<div tabindex="0" class="inner">
```

The **problem**:
I want to make inner div focusable with an outline border, but because of `overflow: hidden;` I can't do it. This is only an example. Also, I don't wanna touch the `overflow: hidden` of the outer div when the focus is on the inner one, so this won't go. Perhaps there's an easy way(code only, no imgs-graphics) to implement some sort of border on the focusable element?

***CSS-HTML code only pls. No JS**

Comment: Why don't you use `border` instead of `outline`

Comment: you might use `outline-offset: -10px` for `.inner:focus`

Comment: fcalderan, post it as an answer please :)

Comment: outline-offset does not work in IE (or Edge)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a negative offset for the `outline` when the div is focused, like so:

```
.inner:focus {
   outline-offset: -10px;
}
```

The value should be equal to the `outline-width`.

---

As an alternative approach you might also use an inset `box-shadow` e.g.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #ff0;
```

Comment: outline-offset does not work with IE (for those still stuck with having to support it)

Comment: This was a really hard bug to fix, thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `::after` property

```
.inner:focus::after {
    content: "";
    height: 90%;
    outline: 10px solid #ffff00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 98.1%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think about this... very wise of you, but fcalderan suggest a much more simpler and effective solution I think

Answer (score 1):

You could use `border` instead of `outline` and set `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.outer:focus {
  outline: 10px solid #00FF00;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F0F;
  left: 50%;
}
.inner:focus {
  border: 10px solid #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="outer">
<div tabindex="0" class="inner">
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the `box-sizing: border-box;`. Very nice solution too

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `box-shadow: inset` or `outline` with negative `outline-offset`

```
.inner:focus::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* #1 */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;

  /* #2 */
  outline: 4px;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```